# Not Being Able To Retrieve My Data From Firebase V9

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[this is what it look like on my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UamcE.png)I have been trying to retrieve data from a collection of users and document of which is generated by the user's UID (USER.UID) the code keeps giving output of Document Not Found.

```js
import { db } from '../Firebase'
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"

getDoc(doc(db, 'users', user?.uid)).then(docSnap => {
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");

    }
  })
```

Comment: Are you certain the you have user data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry, but we don't have an emergency service, hence I removed your plea for urgent help. Just make sure to give enough details in your question to make it answerable. Reading [ask] can help you too.

Comment: Did you verify this `user?.uid` resolves to what you expect? I could be nil, which would cause the code to fail

Comment: Yeah, i did the verification

Comment: We need to see what `db` and `user?.uid` is (output to console please and include that) and your code shown as-is does not run so we we have no way to help. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Important error information is also being ignored as *any* error could cause No Such Document to print. I would suggest adding a `catch (e) {` closure to get more details about the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you could first try to get all data, to see if it works, just in case you were having a problem with "user?.uid" (typo or something like that):

```
getDoc(doc(db, 'users'))
.then(docSnap => {
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    } else {
      console.log("No such document!");

    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks very much I'll try this snippet, I'll let you know when I get to it.